# Use raspberry as a Apple home hub

Tags: home-automation

I have some homekit objects and I would like to use them with apple automation system.

I don't have apple tv or ipad, so I would like to know if a raspberry project exists to do something like this.

I found homebridge project but it seems allow only add object, not working as a hub.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! Have you found a server, which is emulating the home hub or did you end up buying an Apple TV?

Comment: Badly, I don't find anything to do that. And no I don't want to buy an Apple TV. Too expansive for nothing I think.

Answer (score 2):

[Per justme-1968](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/issues/1187#issuecomment-285652703):

> no it is not possible. has been discussed many times.
>
> atv (and iPad) are the only real ways to get remote access and push notifications.

[pdlove followed up with](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/issues/1187#issuecomment-408741044):

> It's how HomeKit's protocol works. It only communicates with the local network due to how the iPhone handles discovery.
> It's conceivably possible to have Homebridge communicate directly with iCloud and emulate and Apple TV or iPad, but the problem with that is that you would have to have a program written that is going to violate the iCloud terms of service and potentially get Apple to come after that project to shut it down.

So - it should not be possible to use a RPi as an Apple Home hub. Sorry for the bad news.

Answer (score 0):

There is a system called: Home Assistant. It has an add on that can get the information from your devices and and pass it on to homebridge app. It's a bit out of the way of how it should work but it should.

This is how I started my really short way with Home Assistant. I looked for a way to work with homekit and found this. I started working with it, got few sensors working and expanding as I go.

I use the Home Assistant application but I know it can work with home bridge as well.